# Collection of markers with Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

I've worked quite a lot with Bing maps but I'm new to Google maps.

With the Bing maps API there is something called `EntityCollection` which represents a group of overlays with useful functions such as get a count, hide or remove all markers within the group. I found it to be quite handy when you want to represent different type of objects on the map.

But after some research I can't seem to find something equivalent in Google Maps. Is there anything similar or would I have to write my own `MarkerCollection` class? Has anyone done this already with some code sample I could have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

There are not functions for every type of command one would like to use on markers, but you can always implement everything manually. Counting is easy, just make a variable and increment it every time a marker is initialized.

To hide a marker

```
marker.setVisible(false);
```

To remove a marker, I believe it is like this (never used it before though)

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

To deal with multiple markers check out this link.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

In particular, I think marker manager is the best. The only annoyance I have had with marker manager is that it didn't function properly when I used markers with labels, and thus had to edit the marker manager.